# Will Automation tool TOSCA supports Amazon web services

Tags: tosca

We planned to move our data centre(SAP) to Amazon web services(AWS) cloud.
So as part of automation testing we already have Tosca test script suite. Need to know does this TOSCA test suite can be reusable in amazon web services

Comment: please elaborate more, what kind of test that you perform. If the application doesn't change much and you test from the application side, the test script will still be usable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, what you mean actually. How will you access your application?

Michael